# Кнопка на финальной странице инсталятора Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Что нужно добавить в код после procedure FinishButtonOnClick , что-бы моя кнопка закрывала инсталятор. Проще говоря выполняла функции стандартной кнопки "Завершить"?

```
procedure FinishButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
//.......................
end;

var
  FinishButton: TNewButton;

Procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
Begin case CurPageID of
wpFinished:
begin
  FinishButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm.FinishedPage);
  FinishButton.Parent := WizardForm;
  FinishButton.Left := ScaleX(200);;
  FinishButton.Top := ScaleY(485);
  FinishButton.Width:=ScaleX(100);
  FinishButton.Caption :=SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish);
  FinishButton.OnClick := @FinishButtonOnClick;
end;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(nil);

А ещё оказывается можно было вот так:

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
Var
ErrorCode: integer;
begin
  Result:= true;
Begin case CurPageID of
wpFinished:
MsgBox('Программа установлена.' #13#13 'Приятного использования', mbInformation, MB_OK)
end;
end;
end;
```